# Android Snackbar Is Hidden Behind System UI

Tags: android, snackbar, android-immersive

I've got a full screen Activity that does a hide/show of the system UI using the following two functions:

```
// This snippet hides the system bars.
public static void hideSystemUI(View view) {
    // Set the IMMERSIVE flag.
    // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the content
    // doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
    view.setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
}

// This snippet shows the system bars. It does this by removing all the flags
// except for the ones that make the content appear under the system bars.
public static void showSystemUI(View view) {
    view.setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Since the UI is laid out in full screen mode when I show a Snackbar and the System UI is showing, it is drawn behind the Navigation bar. I'm not using a `CoordinatorLayout` and currently have no reason to use it. What's the proper way to get the Snackbar to show in the correct place given the current state of the system UI?

Comment: have you resolved this?